# External DVD on Macbook Pro 2018 with multiport adapter

Tags: mojave, usb, thunderbolt, optical-drive, dvd

This model/OS does not support connected CD/DVD drives, it can only use remote devices.

I need to read and write optical media for medical reasons, so being able to use a directly connected drive is more than useful.

An external (generic) DVD connected to a Thunderbolt port is not recognized and it's even not powered, but connecting it to the multiport adapter powers the DVD that is recognized by the Thunderbolt bridge in USB mode, but the device does not really work, nor for audio CDs, nor for video DVDs, nor for data.

I'm half the way on, but I cannot really use it.
Is there a suggested way to get my Mac recognize this peripheral?

Comment: Updating the OS to Mojave 10.14.6 fixed something. The CD/DVD drive was recognised (pan in System Preferences), an audio CD was recognized and I could play it with QuickTime Player and Clementine (after according it full hardware control in the Privacy pan).

Comment: A read/write CD Rom is automatically mounted, but it seems empty (no files); this could be a problem on the filesystem (maybe not properly recognised). After several minutes trying to read the CD, il seems that a list of files is available, but such a long delay is deceptive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems solved by updating Mojave to 10.14.6.

Audio CDs work and most data CDs/DVDs work as expected.

Only RW disks seem difficult to read, but this seems a completely different problem.
So it seems that using a multiport adapter can help connecting a USB CD/DVD drive.